# C# Office / Outlook 2010 Toolbar - HTML Emails - HTMLBody is slow

Tags: c#, html, email, outlook

I'm programming an outlook toolbar that downloads some email templates from the website and then allows creating html emails from prepared html files, This is the code I use for creating an email:

```
        MailItem letter = (MailItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        letter.HTMLBody = @"<div style=""text-align:center""> <b><br/>Please wait for content to be loaded...</b></div>";            
        letter.Display(false);
        letter.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        letter.HTMLBody = buffer.ToString();
```

This is OK in outlook 2003/2007 but so slow in 2010.
I've realized that outlook add lots of crappy code to the email (MSO styles, reformats html and lots of other crap), and this is actually very slow. I thought about forcing outlook to add the crap code to the saved HTML files, I've tried this:

```
            // Compile the file and add the MSO Crap
            MailItem letter = (MailItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            letter.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            letter.HTMLBody = content;
            content = letter.HTMLBody;
```

But the "content" variable still contains the originally formatted HTML. Is this the right direction? How can I get reformatted HTML with the outlook code?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question...

```
public static string HtmlToCrap(String HtmlSource)
{
string HtmlFile = "";
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(HtmlFile, HtmlSource);


Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document oDoc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();
oWord.Visible = false;

oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(HtmlFile);

oDoc.SaveAs(@"C:\WORDhtml.html", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML);

oDoc.Close(false);
oWord.Quit();

return ReadFile(@"C:\WORDhtml.html");
}
```